# How to map Multiple controllers in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two controllers in my Application; one is `userController`, where I have add, delete and update methods; the other one is `studentController`, where I also have add, delete and update methods.

All the mappings are same in my methods using `@RequestMapping` annotation in both controllers. I have one confusion: if we are passing the same action from the JSP, then how will the Dispatcher find the corresponding controller? If anybody could describe this using example will be appreciated.

Comment: Add your code. We need something to work from otherwise people will say just go read the doc.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to set a `@RequestMapping` annotation at the class level the value of that annotation will be the prefix of all requests coming to that controller,
for example:

you can have a user controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("edit")
    public ModelAndView edit(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id, Map<String, Object> model) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and a student controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("student")
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping("edit")
    public ModelAndView edit(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id, Map<String, Object> model) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Both controller have the same method, with same request mapping but you can access them via following uris:

```
yourserver/user/edit
yourserver/student/edit
```

hth

Comment: Can i have each controller in each package or i need to have all controllers inside the same package?

Comment: @BrennoLeal No, it's not really needed to define all the controllers under same package. You can write it as per your requirement. You just have to annotate that controllers with **@Controller** and Spring will get to know about your Controllers wherever(in different packages) they are.

Answer (score 0):

We can have any number of controllers, the URL mapping will decide which controller to call..

Please refer [here](http://javainfinite.com/spring/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-multiple-controllers/) for detailed Spring MVC multiple Controller example