# How to use multiple controllers in Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to use two controllers to process requests in my Spring application, but is not working as expected:

**Controller1** is correctly processing the requests:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appclient")
public class Controller1 {
   ...
}
```

**Controller2** is not processing any message:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/webclient")
public class Controller2 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addProduct () {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I'm using Postman to test my application and I'm getting the following error, meaning there's not controller action defined for *"/webclient/product"*, which is not true.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1497048933216,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/webclient/product"
}
```

If I modify **Controller1** so that it can process *"/webclient/product"*, it works, but is not the way I want to do this.

Any idea why Controller2 is not working?

**EDIT**: Here is the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: There does not seem to be a problem in your definition, are you using spring boot ws ?. Can you add the main class?

Comment: what is the exception or stack-trace are you getting. This is a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068530/how-to-map-multiple-controllers-in-spring-mvc) you can refer.

Comment: Are the controllers in same pckage?

Comment: @Strelok I've been trying several things: Moving both to the same package where the main class is; Placing the controllers in different packages; The same as before plus adding the _scanBasePackages_ parameter in the SpringBootApplication annotation in the main class as explained [here](https://smarterco.de/java-spring-boot-mvc-ontroller-not-called/).None of it worked for me... I know I have to be missing something, the problem is that I don't know what.

Comment: @German I've included the main class. Is quite simple, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already detected my problem, silly of me... I forgot to include the *Thymeleaf* dependency in my `pom.xml`.

**Controller1** is working since it is a RESTful service and it does not depend on *Thymeleaf*, but **Controller2** is based on MVC and is not able to find the templates, and so, is returning that error.

Adding this dependency solved my problem:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It's good practice to use the new `@RestController` for those controllers that need it. Makes it clear that it's a rest API controller and also saves you typing as you do not need to add `@ResponseBody` to the methods

Answer (score 0):

In controller 2 you suppose to return an HTTP response, something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/webclient")
public class Controller2 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addProduct () {
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(header, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

From wiki:

> HTTP functions as a request–response protocol in the client–server
>   computing model

With that being said, you can't just return void. HTTP is request-response based, thus, you must return a response.

The 404 means HTTP not found, in other words, POSTMAN can't find this handler.

Try to add the host, something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/webclient/product
```

and make sure that you're using GET method like you mentioned.

Comment: That was my mistake while copying the code. It returns a `ModelAndView` object, it's corrected now. However, your answer helped me realize what my problem was. I've already posted and answer, so thanks!

Comment: A vote up will be appreciated thanks... @DiegoMoreno